# Create Graphs automatically out of the excel generated via SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services, ssis, vba

I have the following requirement,

A SQL Server 2008 scheduled job that runs at 9 am in the morning. This job should send a spreadsheet with data in a workbook(workbook1) and the chart attached in the next workbook(workbook2). The data must have the values from a SQL table. The chart must reflect the values present in the workbook1. This sheet should be mailed across to n number of users. The n number of users are not even aware of the sql server and dont know anything about the username and password of the server. They must just have the spreadsheet with the two workbooks.

I have decided to do the below

1) Create a stored procedure that formats the data into a table 2) Invoke a SSIS , to copy the data into the workbook1 of excel 3) Create the Graph in the workbook2 of the same excel

The point 1 and 2, I have completed already.

After activity 1 and 2, I will have something like below in the excel

Workbook1:

```
Date | Column A | Column B | Column C |

10-7-14 | 0983883 | 09433344 | 4443333 |

11-7-14 | 0986444 | 06875544 | 4689073 |
```

I am not really able to do the activity 3. Activity 3 must have take in the values from the above table and create graphs in workbook2

I know it can be done with SSRS, but I would like to know other ways as we have only SSIS with us and SSRS is totally out of scope. For some reasons SSRS is restricted to use in our systems.

I have tried various ways to do this. (created a dynamic graph in workbook2 of the excel template for SSIS and let the values transferred to workbook1 renders the graph but it does not work sadly.). I am not able to create dynamic graphs with the empty excel templates that I feed to SSIS.

Excel is the problem here, it does not allows any pre-defined graphs in it. It always expects a value to create a graphs.

I can also go for a VBA macro option,(like creating a button and let the user click the button to generate graphs) but I am not really sure if it is a feasible one?

Excel experts please help !

I might like sound like an amateur but please pardon me as I am new to SSIS and none of my colleagues have an idea on how to do it and I could not get anything with the research I have done, which is a bit frustrating though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't know the specifics of your workbook structure you might need to adapt the following vba code (as the sub name suggests this should be placed in the Open event of the workbook):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim LastColumnLetter As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = ws.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastColumnLetter = Chr(LastColumn + 64)

ws2.Activate

ws2.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range("A1:" & LastColumnLetter & LastRow)

ws2.Range("A1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This code executes when the workbook is opened and first tries to find the range your data table is occupying and then updates the Data Source for the Chart. I have assumed that your data are in Sheet1 and start at cell A1 while your chart (Chart 1) is in Sheet2.

Comment: Thanks much. I will surely try this.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar for work but am using excel as a front end to SSAS but the concept is similar for sql server.

It sounds like you would find a pivot chart in excel useful.  This is due to the fact that excels dynamically renders the chart based on the results of the pivot table.
Note that the pivot table allows for filtering so this means that the user can filter out parts of the data they do not need.  Or if the user wants to alter how the chart looks, e.g. sales by month instead of sales by quarter it is extremely easy for them to do.  So basically the presentaton of the results are being done dynamically in excel.

To create one based off external data you do the following:
 Data --> from other sources 
It is possible for excel to query sql server, though you probably want to limit the result set to a small read-only table for reporting. 
Note that the data source information is saved into the file, with excel being able to use both user name and password hard coded in or the window's domain logins.  Ideally you want to use the domain login over a general username and password

So the solution becomes more like the following:

1. SP or SSIS to populate a table for excel to query.  This means excel is just writing simple selects and group bys
2. Using Data --> from other sources --> from SQL server
3. Create the stock pivot table, which will handle the presentation of the data
4. Give file to users.  The file would have the defined datasource in it
5. They then just hit refresh which will requery the server for the results.
6. User is able to drag and drop fields, which updates the pivot table and redraws the excel chart

The only downside being that the user can only see a copy of the current dataset.

Comment: Thanks, but I might even hand it over to someone who is not in the network. Say someone is accessing from home, who has no network to the office sql servers. So they wont have a connectivity with the backend table. In those cases, do you think this soln will work ?